# Purpose of "stop" in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I read a document about `stop` and some example code with `stop` in it. However, I'm still unsure about the usage of `stop`.

The following is how `stop` is used in the Ants Simple example in the model library. Could anyone help me understand the use of `stop` here?

```
to look-for-food  ;; turtle procedure
                  ;; turtle can access its own patch's property, in this line is `food`
  ifelse  food > 0           ;; if turtle's own patch has food on it
  [ set carrying-food? true  ;; pick up food --> change this turtle's carrying-food property to true

    set food food - 1        ;; let's this patch losing one food

    rt 180                   ;; let turtle turn around

    stop       ;; no idea what is the use of stop here?????????????
  ]
  [ ;; go in the direction where the pheromone smell is strongest
    uphill-pheromone     
  ]
```

Comment: Excellent question. I don't believe it does anything and I just commented it out and the model appears to work the same. This is one of the textbook models and it is possible that it is a hangover from a more complex model that has been simplified for the textbook.

Comment: Thanks JenB! Have you come cross any model example with good uses of `stop`? I am new to netlogo and have not read many models yet.

Comment: The most common use of `stop` (I think) is in the main `go` procedure, to break out of the `forever` button when there's nothing left to do. NetLogo doesn't know that there's nothing left to do and will continue to tick through time. Have a look at the Fire model in the library for an example. Other examples would be an epidemic, when there's no more infectious people.

Comment: Yes, it's most certainly a leftover from the original **Ants** model. We'll fix it. (You can take a look at the original model: there, `stop` actually does something.)

Comment: @JenB Thanks a lot for the explanation and model recommendation!

Comment: @NicolasPayette Thanks for your reply. However, I have checked both **Ants** and **Ants Perspective Demo**. Neither of uses of `stop` break out of the `forever` button.

Comment: the new piece of code with `stop` is inside go forever button:

`ask turtles [ if who >= ticks [ stop ] ;; delay initial departure`

Comment: In **Ants**, `stop` only breaks out of the `look-for-food` procedure, not the forever button. To stop a forever button, you need to do it from the "top level" procedure. See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#buttons.

Answer (score 0):

stop can also be used to stop a BehaviorSpace model run. If the go commands directly call a procedure, then when that procedure calls stop, the run ends.
stop can also be used to stop a forever button.